# How should I create route on with google maps API?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Problem**

Hi, I am new to the google maps API. I want to achieve the results showed in the below image. I was reading the docs in google maps API V3 but couldn't figure out which library should I use to draw the route, show the **KM**(distance) ran by the user or the start and end point marker.

Any help leading to the docs or demo/tutorial provided by google or any developer related to this topic would be great. Thanks in advance.

**Map Image**

[image: Google Maps]

Comment: Please see the [documentation for the DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), if it is a "run", you probably want WALKING directions. [Here is an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_kmmarkers_0.html) that puts "Km" markers every 2 km.

Answer (score 0):

Read this
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

and search for

> distance.value

to display KM